# How to use custom icons instead of Fontawesome icons

Tags: css, html

In this code i have used Fontawesome icons for nav dropdown. Now i have to pass custom icons. can anyone suggest how to achive it?

```
.nav-link-type-one::after,
 li.show .nav-link-type-one::after {
     right: -7px;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 17px;
     top: 1px;
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     content: "\f0d7";
     position: relative;
 }

 .nav-link-type-one::after,
 li.show .nav-link-type-one::after {
     content: "\f0d7";
 }

 li.show .nav-link-type-one::after {
     content: "\f0d8";
     color: #ec7f4a;
 }
```

Comment: from where will you get icons??

Comment: @JoykalInfotech alraedy i having SVG icons

Comment: The idea of Rajesh might be correct but i prefer using them as background-images, unless i have to change their colors or styles frequently

Comment: @JoykalInfotech I tried background-image but i doesn't workout

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site where you can create your own custom icons. You just need to upload your custom created icon SVG and convert that to the font files. You can download that converted files and you can use that in your project.

---- Steps to follow --- 
Click the untitled project in the top right and then click New Project. There you can see Import Icon button on the left top. Import and convert the custom SVG icons that you have created into font files

[IcoMoon Custom font generator](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

Comment: Directly i can not use SVG images ah?

Comment: Yes, you can... Please share the jsFiddle code here.

Comment: In this code instead of fontawosome caret i have to use my icon so can u check and let me know.  https://jsfiddle.net/Harismith/kuq9cb20/

Answer (score 0):

Here I have demonstrated the use of an image as icons in your fiddle
my code is at the bottom.

[check link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lumj0wfe/)

```
.nav-link-type-three::after
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following fiddle will work for you
[JSFiddle Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lecjb27/2/)

```
.nav-link-type-three {
padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
color: white !important;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
margin-right: 1rem;
}
.nav-link-type-three:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link-type-three::after,  li.show .nav-link-type-three::after{
position: absolute;   
background:url("your image path goes here...") no-repeat;
width:16px;
height:16px;
content: "";
 right:0
}
li.show .nav-link-type-three::after{
  transform:rotate(180deg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## INLINE SVG

I find the cleanest and most lightweight solution is to use inline svg's.

The process is simple.

1. Add a hidden div to the top of your root page to contain all your svg (symbols).
2. Add an svg anywhere on your website using the svg refernced using the xlink href.
3. Style globally using single css class.
4. Optionally add differant colours to icons using a second class to any paths/shapes.

```css
.Icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: #113d63;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}
#Icon-Menu .Path2 {
  fill: #b00;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="Icon-Menu" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path class="Path1" d="M93.417,5.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V8.333 C96.417,6.679,95.071,5.333,93.417,5.333z" />
      <path class="Path2" d="M93.417,40.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V43.333 C96.417,41.679,95.071,40.333,93.417,40.333z" />
      <path class="Path1" d="M93.417,75.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V78.333 C96.417,76.679,95.071,75.333,93.417,75.333z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>

<svg class="Icon"><use xlink:href="#Icon-Menu" /></svg>
```

---

### BENEFITS

- Lightweight (Only includes symbols that are used).
- Cross browser compatible.
- Scalable.
- Flexible.
- Customisable.